# Understanding & operator in MySQL where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, bitwise-and

I am trying to solve a programming problem in MySQL. I have the following table.

[image]

I want to get the names of people who have "reading" and "drawing" as interests.

One of the possible outcomes that were given with the solutions is the below.

```
SELECT name
    FROM people_interests
    WHERE interests & 1 AND interests & 8
    ORDER BY name
```

However, I don't understand why this query works here. Can someone explain why this works and what the `&` operator does here?

Comment: PLease read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/bit-functions.html

Comment: Thanks, I read that before posting this, but it doesn't explain this or I don't understand to apply it here.

Comment: Never, ever store data as semi-colon separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: Im trying to understand how & operator works here

Comment: `&` is bitwise AND. And it has higher priority than `AND`. So the expression is `(interests & 1) AND (interests & 8)`. First parenthesis expression tests does least bit is set. Second parenthesis test does 3rd least bit is set. Final `AND` tests does both previous checks gives TRUE. PS. `interests` column must have SET datatype. PPS. Use mnemonic values instead of numeric ones.

Comment: what is the data type of the interests field?

Comment: @Shadow Looks like VARCHAR... SET uses a comma as a delimiter.

Comment: @Akina thanks, so what is the relationship between "reading" and 1, and "drawing" and 8(100)?

Comment: Investigate [SET datatype](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set.html) carefilly.

Comment: @Akina if the data type is varchar, then I cannot really explain why the query works. A set would be an explanation, but the semicolon is putting me off. Hence the question.

Comment: @Shadow *if the data type is varchar, then I cannot really explain why the query works* The query may work only if datatype is SET. But I doubt that this query works on **shown** data - it is simply copypasted from somewhere 100% and is not related to shown data.

Comment: @Akina well, that's a possible explanation. But would really like the OP to answer to be sure.

Comment: This was from code signal platform, so they gave most of the query without 1 and 8 and asked to complete it, the above query with 1 and 8 is the highest voted solution.

Comment: Hello, It is actually a set, please apologize me if I mislead you, it shows ';" seperated input in the test case execution area, but in the problem description it says 
`interests`- the set of interests or hobbies this person has, given as a comma-joined string. This column has datatype `set('reading','sports','swimming','drawing','writing','acting','cooking','dancing','fishkeeping','juggling','sculpting','videogaming')`. I was not aware of the set data type and hence thought it is a String. Also, problem description area has input with comma seperated.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with the same problem but you are missing some important information in your question:

interests - the set of interests or hobbies this person has, given as a comma-joined string. This column has datatype

```
set('reading','sports','swimming','drawing','writing','acting','cooking','dancing','fishkeeping','juggling','sculpting','videogaming').
```

this set is specially important because it is telling you the position of the values you are looking for, in this case 'reading' and 'drawing' position 1 and 4 respectively.

Now, here is the tricky part:

to convert that to binary you are using their position to set the binary value, for example:

reading , position 1 sets the first bit in a binary number 00000001 (remember that the LSB or least significant bit is from right to left).

drawing, position 4 sets the fourth bit in a binary number which is 00001000 
hopefully at this point you realize that if you convert those binary values to decimal they become 1 and 8, and that is the reason of why it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite odd.  I suspect that the intention is to introduce you to the `set` data type in MySQL.  The documentation is [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set.html).

The reason this is strange is the semicolons in the column.  Sets generally use commas as the separator -- this is the documented separator and I don't think there is any way to change them.

That said, sets are generally not recommended for the following reasons:

- They are specific to MySQL.
- They are limited in the number of values that can be stored in the set.
- They can be confusing, because they confound strings, integers, and bit positions.

Under some specific circumstances they can be useful, but most databases do quite well without them.

Comment: Yeah, cannot find any evidence that the separator could be changed. Checked both mysql and mariadb documentation. Perhaps Akina is right, the OP used wrong data for demonstration purposes.